# What is the meaning of the rhombus symbol in a SQL Server ER Diagram?

Tags: sql-server, entity-relationship

What is the meaning of the rhombus symbol in a SQL Server ER Diagram?

I have found this picture of a relationship with rhombus symbol. However in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2008, 2012 and 2014 the relationshiplines are without a rhombus. I think in 2016 and 2017 is it the same.

If there is an option, how do I turn it on to show the rhombus symbol as well.

Thanks for any hints.

[image]

Comment: based on [this article](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/72/sql-joins-and-the-sql-server-management-studio-query-designer) it means it's an inner join.   if it had a box all around it ; it would be a full outer. Box on right 1/2 side a right join box on left 1/2 a left join.

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. I've searched all the time for ER-Diagram but it is all about JOIN. So this is the answer what helps. Could you please make it as an answer so that I accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/how-the-query-and-view-designer-represents-joins-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-2017) provides information using MSFT documentation:

Image below describes what each of those mean.  While the above  link provides more detail direct from MSFT docs.

[image]